# Instance of variable

Tags: c

I have a c code

```
int foo( int *p, int n){

  int a[81];
  int i,v;

  for( i = 0; i < n ; i++){
    a[i]=p[i]

  if( n == 1 ) return a[0];
  v=foo ( a, n-1);
  if( v > a[n-1] )
    return v;
  else
    return a[n-1];
}

int main ( void ){
 int b[81], i;

  for( i = 0; i < 81; i++){
    b[i]=rand();
  foo(b,81);
  return 0;
}
```

And i need to find out how many instances of variable a will exist( max number) my answer was 81 , but it was wrong and i cant find out what number it should be. How could i determine it?

Comment: And what is your approach till time?

Comment: Wel,, I would print something out in the same scope as where 'a' is declared, run the code and count the lines.  Maybe that's just me.

Comment: @Johnyb  Could you elaborate what you are trying to do? As for me then I have understood nothing.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I think that it's asking about the total number of loops and recursion levels... (?)

Answer (score 1):

The main will call the function 82 times and each time the func will call recursively itself 80 times in a loop of decreasing `n` items.

So altogether it will be 81*81.

EDIT: I didn't notice the return after first iteration so actually it's pretty small number.

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: @Martin James : With every call one instance of  `a` will be created. So it's the same number. They will not exist at the same time though.

Comment: i needed to write down exact number , so there has to be way how to count it event without running it

Comment: Well, sure, buth then it's a maths question and off-topic.

Comment: im geting more and more confused by this calculation , how will the return affect the number of instance?

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the number of elements in `a` to be arbitrarily high.
2. Build a *function* to assign elements to `a`, and only use that function to set elements of `a`. You could use this function to make sure that you don't attempt to write outside the bounds of `a`. (Else the behaviour of your program will be undefined and so any results will be meaningless).
3. Encode a "watermark" `static int` in that function to record the largest index accessed.
4. Run your program and note the value of the variable set up for (3).

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global counter - it will be initialized to zero.  In the function, at the same scope as 'a' is declared, increment the counter.

Printf() it out at the end of main().

Comment: Would that not work?